# Send email to everyone using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365, email

I am wanting to send an email notification to everyone when something has been posted to our blog site. I have set up a workflow and the email template, I have tested the workflow with myself and I receive an email whenever something is posted. However when I change the recipient of the email to the group All Users, nothing is sent to anyone.

I have tried the default groups All Users (windows), All Users (membership) and the everyone one.

Please could someone help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All Users` is probably not an email enabled group. As far as I know you can send emails to email groups that have been defined in Active Directory, but not to all users authenticated to SharePoint. Check if your Active Directory contains such a group and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I looked at Active Directory groups but I would preferably want a dynamic distribution group so that I can email everyone. However these can't be used. Any suggestions apart from just manually creating a list of everyone and maintaining it?

Comment: There are many different ways in Active Directory / Exchange / On-boarding management to ensure that all active users are members of a particular group. Assuming that new users are not created manually in your organisation, this would be part of the automated procedure to set up new users.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it eventually through the use of active directory!